# Net Maui, get the serial number of the device

Tags: android, nuget, maui, serial-number

Is there a way to get te serial number of the device (android) in Net Maui?

I tried with the namespace Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo but It doesn't have it.
I used to get it in Xamarin.Forms with the nuget Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo (DeviceInfoPlugin).
Is there something similar in Net Maui?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9395

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get the serial number of the device since android 10.0. The [official document about the restriction on non-resettable device identifiers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids) said:

> Starting in Android 10, apps must have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission in order to access the device's non-resettable identifiers, which include both IMEI and serial number.

And the `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` permission is a system permission which can't be granted to the third party application.